# lazy loading meteor subscription

Tags: mongodb, meteor, lazy-loading

Say I subscribe 10 documents when the page is rendered  and subscribe more documents as and when needed. Basically I am showing images to the user. So when the page is opened, I want to subscribe the first 5 documents. Now when the user is on 3rd document, I want to subscribe the next 5. Any help on how to proceed??

I can subscribe to the first 10 documents using limit property of mongodb. I know when to fire the next meteor.subscribe call but how should I mention that it should subscribe the next five documents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple pattern to do this is to use a [Session](https://docs.meteor.com/api/session.html) variable or a [reactiveVar](https://docs.meteor.com/api/reactive-var.html) to track how many items you want to load then have a [Tracker.autorun()](https://docs.meteor.com/api/tracker.html#Tracker-autorun) update the subscription automatically when that changes.

Initialize (when you're setting up the layout):

```
Session.set('nDocs',10);
```

Tracker:

```
Tracker.autorun(() => {
  Meteor.subscribe('myPublication', Session.get('nDocs'));
});
```

Event Handler (triggered when the user views the 3rd doc in your case):

```
someEvent(ev){
  Session.set('nDocs', Session.get('nDocs')+10);
}
```